# scanf ends my program and no error is thrown

Tags: c, input, undefined-behavior, string-literals

I am a beginner in C and I encountered problems when dealing with `scanf`, hoping for an explanation behind this

this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int fav_charac() {
    char *string = ""; 
    printf("whats your fav letter?: ");
    scanf("%s", string);                         // the problem
    printf("your fav letter is %s\n", string);
}

int main() {
    fav_charac();
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the program running

```
whats your fav letter?: a

C:\Users\DELL\source\repos\hello C\x64\Debug\hello C.exe (process 15052) exited with code -1073741819.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

as you can see it exited right after an input is made, why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent scanf causing a buffer overflow in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scanf` will attempt to write to `string`, which is `.rodata`. That means, the Data in `string` can only be read from but not written to. Use `char string[64];` or something similar. This will place the variable into `.data`. Also limit user input in `scanf` with `scanf("%63s", string);` so that scanf won't write out of bounds.

Full example:

```c
char string[64];
scanf("%63s", string);
```

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation, I thought `char *something` is a good practice thanks for correcting me. the code worked too. so `rodata` is immutable and `data` is mutable, from what I learnt `const` also creates immutable data, does this mean `*something` functions same as `const`?

Comment: No its specific to strings. If you are initilizing a variable with a string-value, the string will be immutable. `char * str = "some_string";` and `char str2[] = "another_string";` will both be immutable. This is just how the compiler does things. The * means it is a pointer to a memory location. (arrays and pointers work pretty much the same that is why str[] and *str are basically interchangable). The important thing is the `[length]` which will cause the compiler to make the data mutable.

Comment: I recommend you look a bit into pointers, they are confusing but very powerful. When you understand the inner functionality of pointers, you wont think in data-types anymore but rather in bytes and this is pretty fun.

Comment: Off-by-one "`char string[64];` ... `scanf("%64s", string);`" should be `scanf("%63s", string);`.

Comment: @Cediwelli: Your 2nd example `char str2[] = "another_string";`, actually is mutable. It's initialized to `another_string`, but within its bounds can be altered. If you want `str2` to be immutable, you've to write `char const str2[] = …` (or `const char …`).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica True. I just copy-pasted the 64, will edit.

Comment: @datenwolf Where in the obj is it stored? I just looked at the .data section and couldn't find it, which is why I assumed it is in .rodata but it is in neither of them?

Comment: @Cediwelli: You'd see it in `.data` only if it were in global scope. For variable in automatic storage the actual "memory" has no correspondence in the symbol table, the storage space is allocated at runtime (most usually from the stack) and initialized in "some" way (which can be anything but most usually is a copy from data in `.rodata`).

Answer (score 4):

In this declaration

```
char *string = "";
```

there is declared a pointer to an empty string literal that is represented in memory as one byte with the terminating zero value `{ '\0' }`.

And in this call

```
scanf("%s", string);
```

you are trying to change the string literal pointed to by the pointer `string`. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
> elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
> modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

By this reason it is always better to declare pointers to string literals with the qualifier `const`.

```
const char *string = "";
```

By the way in C++ opposite to C string literals have types of constant character arrays. So for such a declaration in C++

```
char *string = "";
```

the C++ compiler will issue a message.

If you want to enter more than one character then declare a character array as for example

```
char string[10] = "";
```

and use the following call of `scanf`

```
scanf( "%9s", string );
```

If you want to enter only one character then declare an object of the type `char` as for example

```
char c = '\0';
```

and use the following call of `scanf`

```
scanf( " %c", &c );
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 char string[50];  // [ the max of letters you want in your string ] 
    printf("whats your fav letter?: ");
    scanf("%s", string);
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", string);` lacks a _width_ limit and is worse than `gets()`.